# Comparing the two tables does not produce the desired result. How can I fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I want to compare two tables. 
However, they are not compared on the same date.

1.table name : hospital_payment_data

```
id    chart_num        chart_name          visit            card_amount_received
1        9740             t1             2019-01-02               500                        
2        9740             t1             2019-01-02               500           
3        23143            t2             2019-01-02               2000                        
4        14220            t3             2019-01-02               3000
```

2.table name : credit_card

```
id           card_date             advenced_amount
1           2019-01-02                 1000        
2           2020-01-02                 2000   
3           2020-01-02                 3000
```

3.table name : charts

```
 id               name
9740               t1     
23143              t2          
14220              t3
```

When i send a query, i get the following:

```
select
  charts.id as chart_num,
  visit,
  charts.name as chart_name,
  sum(card_amount_received) as card_amount_received,
  credit_card.card_date,
  credit_card.amount as amount,
  if(credit_card.amount = sum(card_amount_received), 'ok', 'error') as result
from hospital_payment_data
join charts on charts.id = chart_num
left join credit_card on date(credit_card.card_date) = visit
group by chart_num, visit
```

bad error result:

[image]

***I Want Result***

[image]

How to fix my query? Pleas help me.

Comment: your bad error result and expected result are the same

Comment: modify complete

Comment: It is common JOIN multiplying. Calculate sums in subquery then join another tables.

Comment: I think you're missing a column in credit_card table as there is no way to link this table record to any of the card within the hospital_payment_data table except for the dates. There should be another  foreign key here to link to which card the record belongs to

Comment: @Akina can you explain detail to me?

Comment: @sicKo Only three kinds of information are given. ㅜㅜ

Comment: Fix your sample data. These ids in charts can't be 1,2,3

Comment: @user1082164 take a look at your credit_card table. There's no way to link the records with hospital_payment_data table. The dates is the same for all

Comment: Isn't there another column in the table `credit_card` so you can join? You can't join only on dates.

Comment: @forpas I'm afraid not. There are only id, card_date and amount on the credit_card table.
Isn't there a solution?

Comment: No, a date column is not enough to join properly the rows.

Comment: @forpas If so, can i compare only the amount at random?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I join two tables and compare them? (I've asked several times, but I couldn't find the answer.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199435/how-do-i-join-two-tables-and-compare-them-ive-asked-several-times-but-i-coul)

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is invalid. Your data in table `credit_card` should be identifiable and you should link payment with the debt. For now there are two solutions.

1. Adding new column `card_id` or `chart_num_id` to table `credit_card`. You can then periodically run script assigning value of `card_id` to the card, if you are not able to do it in moment of adding rows to that table. But... what if there will be 2 debts of 2000$ and you will receive only one payment 2000$. It's impossible then to assign one payment to the correct ID without additional information about that payment.
2. Checking payments daily grouping on dates not cards. You can modify SQL script by checking sums of payments for each day. Now you group payments on `chart_num` and instead you can group on `card_date` and `visit`.
3. You can still construct valid SQL query but very complex and I totally don't see any point why this would more desirable over 1. idea. A lot of effort for almost none profit.

Comment: Can you explain in detail your mention?

Comment: I edited my answer. What solution you want to get detailed?

Answer (score 0):

It is common JOIN multiplying. Calculate sums in subquery then join another tables.

> can you explain detail to me? – user1082164

Imagine there is a table

```
id   val
 1   100
 1   200
```

The sum of `val` is 300.
Imagine there is another table

```
id   txt
 1   'A'
 1   'B'
```

joined to first one by `id`. While joining each row from 1st table will be joined to each matched row of 2nd table:

```
SELECT id, val, txt FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (id);

id   val  txt
 1   100  'A'
 1   200  'A'
 1   100  'B'
 1   200  'B'
```

Now the sum of `val` in joined aglomerate is 600 - it is multiplied by each-to-each joining.

For to get correct sum we must firstly sum by single table in a subquery (without joining multiplication effect) then join another table to the summing subquery.

PS. I will not edit your query - it does not match to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY setting.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: I don't think that answer is applicable to the issue, because there is no ID link between tables.

Comment: @Tajniak Some link exists - so it's applicable. It is not primary key. As you can see `id` is a common field (it is not even unique). Imagine it is named not `id` but `some_column`.

Comment: But we cannot link `hospital_payment_data.id` and `credit_card.id`. If it was that, then id 2 in table `hospital_payment_data` should be also 1. Only one way we can link this data is by date. And it seems that in this table there are 2 keys.

Comment: @Tajniak My answer goal is NOT to solve OP's issue - I only explain why the sum value is increased. Maybe you know the term equal to used "JOIN multiplying" which does not need in additional explainations?

Comment: So it's not applicable to OP's issue as I mentioned before.